# How to create list of sections from list of consecutive points

Tags: java, functional-programming

This problem is easily solved with classical for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {
    PointAG p1 = this.points.get(i);
    PointAG p2 = this.points.get(i + 1);
    sections.add(new LineSection(p1, p2));
}
```

Is there a possibility to achieve the same in a functional way, for example with two iterators?

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what *you* mean by "in functional way".

If you mean "using streams", then the following might be one way:

```
List<LineSection> sections = IntStream.range(1, points.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> new LineSection(this.points.get(i - 1), this.points.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But that isn't really any shorter or easier to read than a normal `for` loop, so why do it?

```
List<LineSection> sections = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++)
    sections.add(new LineSection(this.points.get(i - 1), this.points.get(i)));
```

Comment: Compiler showed an error. mapToObj needs to be used instead of map

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a single iterator thus:

```
Iterator<PointAG> it = points.iterator();
if (it.hasNext()) {
  PointAG prev = it.next();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    PointAG next = it.next();
    sections.add(new LineSection(prev, next));
    prev = next;
  }
}
```

You can write the loop body without any extra variables:

```
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    sections.add(new LineSection(prev, prev = it.next()));
  }
```

This exploits the guaranteed left-to-right evaluation order of Java, meaning that the first `prev` is evaluated before the re-assignment. This might not be the best approach: side effects inside expressions are easy to miss when reading code; use the one you are comfortable reading.

Doing it like this - with an iterator - will be more efficient than indexing for non-`RandomAccess` list implementations, for example `LinkedList`.

Comment: You can even declare `prev` inline: `for (PointAG prev = it.next(); it.hasNext(); )`